# Inserting the value of a column that has a default value into another table via a trigger gives null values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that uses a sequence as a default value in one of the columns. Whenever there is an insert into this table, I would like to insert the value of the sequence into another table. However when doing this, I get null values for the values generated by the sequence. Here is example code:

```
create sequence usq_test
  as bigint
  increment by 1
  start 1
  minvalue 1
  maxvalue 9223372036854775807
  no cycle
  owned by none;

create table test1(
  id bigint default nextval('usq_test') primary key,
   name text not null);

insert into test1(name) values ('test_name');
insert into test1(name) values ('test_name');
insert into test1(name) values ('test_name');

select * from test1;
```

```
| id |   name    |
|----|-----------|
|  1 | test_name |
|  2 | test_name |
|  3 | test_name |
```

Now when I add the second table, and define the trigger function:

```
create table test2(id bigint primary key);

create or replace function ufn_insert_trg() returns trigger as
$$
begin
  insert into test2(id)
  values (NEW.id);
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;

create trigger utr_test1_insert
  after insert
  on test1
execute function ufn_insert_trg();

insert into test1(name) values ('test_name');
```

I get:

```
[2019-04-04 14:00:45] [23502] ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
[2019-04-04 14:00:45] Detail: Failing row contains (null).
[2019-04-04 14:00:45] Where: SQL statement "insert into test2(id)
[2019-04-04 14:00:45] values (NEW.id)"
[2019-04-04 14:00:45] PL/pgSQL function ufn_insert_trg() line 3 at SQL statement
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `FOR EACH ROW` to your trigger.

Comment: Well that fixes it - thanks. Can you provide some guidance as to why?

Comment: If you don't specify `FOR EACH ROW`, by default your trigger will be statement-level, i.e. it's fired once per statement rather than one per row. Statement-level triggers don't have NEW/OLD variables (or rather, they're NULL), which makes sense because which of the 100 inserted rows (for example) would NEW refer to?

Comment: I see - makes sense. Is there any way to achieve what I was after at a statement level?

Comment: If you only want to get the latest value from the sequence into `test2`, even if multiple rows were created in a single statement and therefore multiple sequence values will have been issued, and you understand you'll be missing the intervening values, then your trigger function could just insert the last value of the actual sequence (`SELECT last_value FROM usq_test`). However this is very hacky and you'll probably have issues with concurrency.

Comment: No, I want every value inserted in test2. Looks for each row is the way to go. You should write that as an answer so I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your trigger:

> ```
> create trigger utr_test1_insert
>   after insert
>   on test1
> execute function ufn_insert_trg();
> ```

Because you didn't explicitly state whether the trigger is row-level or statement-level, by default it becomes a statement-level trigger.

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> FOR EACH ROW
>
> FOR EACH STATEMENT
>
> This specifies whether the trigger
>   function should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger
>   event, or just once per SQL statement. If neither is specified, FOR
>   EACH STATEMENT is the default.

And also as per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), the `NEW` and `OLD` variables in a statement-level trigger are NULL, which makes sense because any number of rows could have been affected in a statement, so it wouldn't really make sense for `NEW` or `OLD` to refer to any specific one - you're dealing with a statement rather than specific rows.

That's why `NEW.id` is NULL. By changing the trigger to a row-level trigger, it will be fired for every row affected, and the `NEW`/`OLD` variables will be set as expected.

So:

```
create trigger utr_test1_insert
  after insert
  on test1
  for each row
execute function ufn_insert_trg();
```

Comment: Is there any way to do what I want using a statement level trigger?

Comment: @ThatDataGuy Not really. Basically you have to determine, after the fact, which records have been newly written. You'd have to do something like have a previously saved last id somewhere, look it up, and select records where the id > saved id, then save the max id again. A row level trigger is the appropriate type of construct for what you want to achieve. A valid alternative would be to do it without triggers, e.g. as part of the INSERT statement. Something like `WITH x AS (INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id) INSERT INTO audit_table SELECT id FROM x`

Comment: That's what I thought too. The 'returning' approach is much faster than triggers it seems, but I have to remember to structure all my inserts like that if I want all the ids in test2 to be present.